# Uninstalled Postgres but still staus shows output

Tags: postgresql

I uninstalled Postgres by following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation).

Now when I type `sudo service postgresql status`, it gives the following result

```
postgresql.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jan 15 12:02:37 induP systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jan 15 12:02:37 induP systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Jan 15 16:58:50 induP systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Jan 15 16:58:57 induP systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably did not stop progress before you removed it.

Find the process using `ps -ef | grep postgres`  to confirm it is still running. Then kill it with `kill -9 {process_id}` or `pkill -9 postgres`.

Comment: I ran `pkill -9 postgres`, but `ps -ef | grep postgres` still gives result as `indu     15184  8653  0 18:01 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn postgres`

Comment: put it into the question and line out the lines :)  That one line could be the result showing the grep itself and be harmless.