# How to remove psql from Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql

I am able to uninstall postgresql from Ubuntu. But I cannot seem remove the client - `psql`.

I've tried the steps listed here: [How to remove Postgres from my installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation). But it still doesn't work

Comment: What are the exact error messages that you get?

Comment: what does `sudo apt purge psql*` return?

Comment: no error message. the psql CLI just still works fine.

Comment: Thank you @tatsu - that worked

Comment: I see that the app is actually `postgresql-client-common`. Though I'm pretty sure I did an `apt remove` on that too

Comment: I'm aware @tatsu - there is a minimum time limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the command you are looking for is :

```
sudo apt purge postgresql-client-common
```

purge is different from remove as it will also remove the dependencies that only this app uses.

Comment: Thank you. what does this purge command do that uninstall doesn't?

Comment: `psql*` is not the proper string to purge on.

Comment: but if I put the exact package then you don't need `purge` either. purge can be really handy when you are in a scenario where don't want any of the app left on your system and you don't know what package name you are looking for. in this case it worked for him, I assume, because `postgresql-client-common` was one of the dependencies pulled when installing `psql`.

Comment: I've been looking for this for years! I had a postgres installation on my macbook that was interfering with a docker container running postgres on the default port 5432, and I never figured out how to remove the local postgres install, so in that fleet of containers I had to use a `docker-compose.override.yml` file to remap the ports to avoid the conflict... a similar problem just came up (but not the same - I wanted to remove pg latest and install an earlier version for some testing), and I found this - thank you!

Comment: What I wonder, though, is why is it not obvious how to uninstall pg, why is this command not on the pg website (AFAIK), why does `apt-get --purge remove postgresql` not work, and why are there only 3 upvotes for this answer??