# install postgis on ubuntu 18.04 after upgrading gdal to 3.0.4

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, postgresql

I upgraded `GDAL` on my ubuntu 18.04 server to `GDAL 3.0.4` and downgraded Postgres from 12 to 11

After finishing  GDAL upgrade (gdal installtion done according to follow link [Install GDAL Packages on Ubuntu](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html) ):

`ogrinfo --version`

`Collecting GDAL==3.0.4`

Status other GDAL packages after installation :

1. LibGDAL

**`dpkg -l | grep libgdal`**

`libgdal-dev 3.0.4+dfsg-1~bionic0  amd64  libgdal26   3.0.4+dfsg-1~bionic0  amd64`

**`ldconfig -p | grep gdal`**

`libgdal.so.26 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so.26 libgdal.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgdal.so`

2. GdalDATA

**`dpkg -l | grep gdal-data`**

`gdal-data  3.0.4+dfsg-1~bionic0 all`

**Now, when I try to install `PostGIS` `sudo apt install postgis postgresql-11-postgis-3` on my fresh installed `PostgresSQL 11.8` I getting following error**:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: postgis : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed Recommends: postgresql-12-postgis-3 but it is not going to be installed`

Then I tried:

`sudo apt install libgdal20`

`libgdal20 : Depends: gdal-data (>= 2.4.2+dfsg-1~bionic0) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

**UPDATE**
Steps I downgraded PostrgeSQL:
[Completely remove PostrgeSQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32730/how-to-remove-postgres-from-my-installation)

1. `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove postgresql*`
2. `sudo apt purge postgresql-client-common`
3. `dpkg -l | grep postgres`
   --> remove the rest of packages: `sudo apt-get --purge remove` `<pkg_name>`

**Please help me to fix the error , I'm stuck here**

Comment: From Error you received look like latest GDAL supports Postgres 12. It is dependency of latest GDAL. How did you downgrade from Postgres 12 to Postgres 11 ?

Comment: @KKPatel Please see **UPDATE**

Comment: I'm encountering the exact same issue. Seems PostGIS needs libgdal2 and after installing gdal 3 we I can't install libgdal2

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can compile from source as follows:

```
wget https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-3.1.2.tar.gz
tar xf postgis-3.1.2.tar.gz
cd postgis-3.1.2
./configure
make && sudo make uninstall && sudo make install
```

I haven't tested this for PostgreSQL 11, but it works for 12 and gdal 3 if I recall.